# How to abort jenkins job if git push fails?

Tags: git, bash, jenkins

I have the following line of code, which is intended to fail safe; i.e. immediately abort my jenkins job if git push fails for whatever reason:

```
sh "set +x -e; git push https://${user}:${pass}@${repo} master 2>/dev/null"
```

My understanding is that the `-e` option passed to `set` should ensure this. However I have recently seen one example of the job continuing to run despite the git push failing.

Is it possible for git to return a successful status code despite failing to push?

Is there a more reliable way to check for failure?

Answer (score 0):

BUILD ID URL/term - forcibly terminates a build